# mapping strings

Tags: string, algorithm, hash

I want to map some strings(word) with number. the similar the string, the nearer their value(mapped number) . also, while checking the positional combination of the letters should impact the mapping.the mapping function should be function of letters, positions (combination given position of letter thepriority such as pit and tip should be different), number of letters.

Well, I would give some examples : **starter, stater , stapler, startler, tstarter** are some words. These words are of format "(*optinal)sta(*opt)*er"  where * denotes some sort of variable in our case it is either 't' or 'l' (i.e. in case of starter and staler). these all should be mapped INDIVIDUALLY, without context to other such that their value are not of much difference. and later on which creating groups I can put appropriate range of numbers for differentiating groups.

So while mapping the string their values should be similar.   there are many words, so comparing each other would be complex. so mapping with some numeric value for each word independently and putting the similar string (as they have similar value) in a group and then later find these pattern by other means.

So, for now I need to look up for some existing methods of mapping such that similar strings (I guess I have clarify the term 'similar' for my context) have similar value and these value should be different to the dissimilar ones. please, again I emphasize that the number of string would be huge and comparing each with other is practically impossible(or computationally expensive and much slow).SO WHAT I THINK IS TO DEVISE AN ALGORITHM(taking help from existing ones) FOR MAPPING WORD(STRING) **ON ITS OWN**

Have I made you clear? Please give me some idea to start with. some terms to search and research.

I think I need some type of "**bad**" hash function to hash strings and then put them in bucket according to that hash value. at least some idea or algorithm names.

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/3422820/10396

Comment: ok...but he is not active there, i cant contact him and the answers are not relevant, i really want the solution through interaction with each comments and improvement of my questions throughout. i cant do that in other's post

Answer (score 0):

Seems like it would best to use a known algorithm like [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: thanks i am looking it in detail. lets see if i can use it to meet my requirements. thanks

Comment: i went through the Levenshtein Distance, what i found is that this is for comparing two strings. But where i am going to implement this consists of huge amount of data. i have tried comparing around million integers(of around 10 digits) it took long time. So i thing, string to string comparison is quite out of equation. so What i mean is THERE MAY BE SOME OF THE EXISTING METHODS TO MAP STRING BY NUMERIC VALUE ON ITS OWN , SUCH THAT whenever new string comes then we could map them with numeric value(using same approach) and put directly into suitable group(gruop consists of numeric range)

Comment: i dont mind if there are collisons while mapping but at the end whenever new word appear and we map it according to this approach , it should have mapped value close to the value of already mapped string. thanks

Answer (score 0):

[This search on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=similar+strings)
 reveals [this question about finding-groups-of-similar-strings-in-a-large-set-of-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3329297/finding-groups-of-similar-strings-in-a-large-set-of-strings), which links to this [article describing a SimHash](http://matpalm.com/resemblance/simhash/) which sounds exactly like what you want.

Comment: ok the problem is same but i cant comment on answers there, that problem is talking about small set of string(100) but here i have to deal with streaming strings(millions of strings(actually logs) within some time). my intensions is not to find similarity algorithms like Levenshtein or jaccard_index coz that need passing string as parameter for comparing which is impossible in my case. I just need some way of hashing(scoring) such that the hash value doesn't change signifiacntly for small change in string. and obviously the strings are unstructural.

Comment: Right.  The last  link gives exactly that:  Simhash is a method for generating a hash value for any given single string where the resulting value should be similar for similar strings.

Comment: thanks Ashelly, i am currently studying simhash. lets see if i need any help i can easily post here, while commenting on other post is quite hard.